# Microsoft Cognitive Services Emotion API: Video Aggregate Result Frequency

Tags: c#, api, azure-media-services, azure-cognitive-services, emotion

Is there a way to set how frequently to produce aggregate results when analyzing emotions in videos?

I am currently using the Microsoft Cognitive Services Emotion API (https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/emotion-api), but I cannot find any documentation on this.

While doing some research, I found that it is possible to set the interval using Azure Media Analytics (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-face-and-emotion-detection/). Specifically by setting a preset such as:

```
{  
  "version": "1.0", 
  "options": {
    "aggregateEmotionWindowMs": "987",
    "mode": "aggregateEmotion",
    "aggregateEmotionIntervalMs": "342"
  }
}
```

I'm looking for something similar with the Microsoft Cognitive Services Emotion API.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible through Microsoft Cognitive Services today.  You can only set presets when the service is invoked via Azure Media Services.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that you can set the detection interval via the Media Service Redactor. Is there a specific reason you need to use the Cognitive API?

Comment: I am using the Cognitive API because I was not aware of emotion detection with Azure Media Analytics.